# Grails Turn off Eager Fetching hasMany with Restful Controller or Resource

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

Take the example of domain classes `User` and `Role` as resources:

```
@Resource(uri='/api/user', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class User {
    String username
    String password
    static hasMany = [roles: Role]
}

@Resource(uri='/api/role', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Role {
    String authority
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    static belongsTo = [User]
}
```

Both `/api/user` and `/api/user/1` would fetch the associated `Role` objects. How to make `/api/user` returns ONLY a list of `User` objects WIHTOUT fetching the associated `Role` objects, while `/api/user/1` would return both `User` object with `id=1` and the associated `Role` objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by ... writing your own implementation. The `@Resource` implementation for Grails does not support these very specific features you are looking for. Implement your own controller that manages the `fetchMode` to meet your own needs.

Comment: It looks like that the marshaller is the key. By default the hasMany fetching is lazy, for both collection and a single object. But the default marshaller would return the hasMany object. Register a custom marshaller which does not put the hasMany object in the map would prevent both `/api/user` and `/api/user/1` return the hasMany objects, but sees no way to tell the marshaller if we are going to return a collection or a single object